# Carousel View in Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: c#, ios, json, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a web service and I'm getting imageurl from json string. But I guess wrong binding section. There isn't show any image. Here is my code.

Xaml:

```
<cv:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingContext.Hotel.HotelImages, Source={x:Reference HotelDetailPage}}" HeightRequest="200">
        <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout HeightRequest="200">
              <Grid HeightRequest="200">
                <Image Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding FullPath}"/>
              </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
          </DataTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
      </cv:CarouselView>
```

and here is my get json service code;

```
for (int j = 0; j < imageCount; j++)
{
        HotelImageModel hotelImage = new HotelImageModel();    
        hotelImage.FullPath = json["data"][i]["HotelImages"][j]["FullPath"].Value;    
        hotel.HotelImages.Add(hotelImage);
}
```

Note: I got help at this example: https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview

Comment: Is your image coming from a HTTPS source? Check your output window. iOS is getting more and more strict on using secure connections only.

Comment: Images coming json service so json string I converting deserialize.

Comment: How do you convert JSON string to image? Is it an Image URL? Can you post a sample JSON? What is `i` and `json` in your get json service code?

Comment: I didn't convert images I'm using imageUrl. I only converting json to string. i is hotels' index number and json is using convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the URL's you are converting are referring to a accessible link? (I assume a url?)
Can you give us the full code?

Just a suggestion but I notice that your var hotel is written like 'hotel' in the code-behind file and written 'Hotel' in your XAML-file ...

I wrote some SO documentation about CarouselView, but the material is now below. In this documentation, you will find a very easy example. Maybe an idea to test it out with your issue and some dummy data?

---

## CarouselView — Pre-release version

### Import CarouselView

The easiest way to import CarouselView is to use the NuGet-Packages Manager in Xamarin / Visual studio:
[image]

To use pre-release packages, make sure you enable the 'Show pre-release packages' checkbox at the left corner.

Each sub-project (.iOS/.droid./.WinPhone) must import this package.

### Import CarouselView into a XAML page

### The basics

In the heading of ContentPage, insert following line:

```
xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
```

Between the  tags place the CarouselView:

```
<cv:CarouselView x:Name="DemoCarouselView">
</cv:CarouselView>
```

x:Name will give your CarouselView a name, which can be used in the C# code behind file.
This is the basics you need to do for integrating CarouselView into a view.
The given examples will not show you anything because the CarouselView is empty.

### Creating bindable source

As example of an ItemSource, I will be using a ObservableCollection of strings.

```
public ObservableCollection<TechGiant> TechGiants { get; set; }
```

TechGiant is a class that will host names of Technology Giants

```
public class TechGiant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TechGiant(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

After the InitializeComponent of your page, create and fill the ObservableCollection

```
TechGiants = new ObservableCollection<TechGiant>();
TechGiants.Add(new TechGiant("Xamarin"));
TechGiants.Add(new TechGiant("Microsoft"));
TechGiants.Add(new TechGiant("Apple"));
TechGiants.Add(new TechGiant("Google"));
```

At last, set TechGiants to be the ItemSource of the DemoCarouselView

```
DemoCarouselView.ItemsSource = TechGiants;
```

### DataTemplates

In the XAML - file, give the CarouselView a DataTemplate:

```
<cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```

Define a DataTemplate. In this case, this will be a Label with text bind to the itemsource and a green background:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

That's it! Run the program and see the result!

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've solved problem. It was caused Xamarin.Forms version.